# Libgdx | Set black color to everything outside of circle

Tags: opengl-es, libgdx

How can I set a black color to the whole screen, excluding a shaperenderer circle? The circle is basically my game world, anything that leaves it shouldn't be visible. Is there some way to create a reverse circle pixmap (eg..A circle, but inverted) to overlay everything except for the circle game area? Or maybe a way to clear the screen, excluding parts? Thanks!

Comment: Why not just not rendering anything but the circle?

Comment: @m.antkowicz I'm not sure your understood the question. The circle is my game world, if an object leaves, then I wan't to to disappear. If the player goes halfway out of the game area (circle), then I wan't however much of the player that is outside to disappear. I thought about creating a black image with a hole in it, then displaying it over everything, but that wouldn't scale well I don't think.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the approach you mentioned in the comments.  Using a black image with a circular hole in it.  Then have each assigned to a different camera much in the same way you would set up a HUD in libgdx.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at shaders, this approach is really flexible and lets you even control how rapid the transition is. Just the basics of GLSL should be sufficient.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=caQZKeAYgD8 Here's a decent tutorial.